# Add icon(logo) in app toolbar - empty activity

Tags: java, android

I used these lines of code in Java:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
```

But my logo looks like this:

LOGO:

[image]

How can I set width of this logo or so it actually looks like a logo? :)

Comment: what is the size of your logo image?

Comment: 300x300 pixels.

Comment: reduce the size and check it

Comment: Thanks. it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add image in toolbar and arrange in the center accordingly.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Go to your layout xml file of activity or fragment, add this in the top. Check this link for more info about Toolbar and its usage [Toolbar usage] (http://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout)

Comment: Oh, well. I understand now. Thanks! :)